# SOAP exception at service.Fetch

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

I'm trying to download attachments and notes from the Contract entity in a crm4 environment to upload to crm 2011 environment.

I get a SOAP exception at line (//String result = service.Fetch(sfetch);)

```
// --------- Server Name -----------
string OrgName = "USF";
string CrmSite = "http://crm4";
string TmpFolder = "C:\\TempAnnotation\\";


CrmAuthenticationToken token = new CrmAuthenticationToken();
token.AuthenticationType = 0;
token.OrganizationName = OrgName;
CrmService service = new CrmService();

service.Url = CrmSite + "/mscrmservices/2007/crmservice.asmx";
service.CrmAuthenticationTokenValue = token;
//service.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

service.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain");

string sfetch = @"<fetch mapping='logical'><entity name='contract'>
                    <attribute name='modifiedon' />
                    <attribute name='title' />
                    <link-entity name='annotation' from='objectid' to='contractid'>
                      <attribute name='annotationid'/>
                      <attribute name='createdon'/>
                      <attribute name='createdby'/>
                      <attribute name='documentbody'/>
                      <attribute name='filename'/>
                      <attribute name='isdocument'/>
                      <attribute name='mimetype'/>
                      <attribute name='notetext'/>
                    </link-entity>
                    </entity>
                </fetch>
            ";

String result = service.Fetch(sfetch);
```

Comment: System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException was unhandled
  Message=Server was unable to process request.
  Source=System.Web.Services
  Actor=""
  Lang=""
  Node=""
  Role=""

Comment: Is possible to more than 10000 records in result?

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine when I tried.

Can you add a try/catch block as such to see additional error details?

```
catch (System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException ex)
{
     string error = ex.Message + " : " + ex.Detail.InnerText;
}
```

Comment: "Server was unable to process request. : \n  0x80040216\n  An unexpected error occurred.\n  Platform\n"

Comment: I'm using v. 5.0.9 of the CRM SDK

Comment: How do I check my CRM SDK version?

Comment: I too am using 5.0.9.  However, it's a stand-alone solution with a web reference.  Not sure what sdk version has to do with this.

Comment: Sorry - misunderstood - I ran against CRM 4.0 with update roll up 19 applied.